# Using a ref cursor as input type with ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, ref-cursor

I'm trying to use a `RefCursor` as an input parameter on an Oracle stored procedure. The idea is to select a group of records, feed them into the stored procedure and then the SP loops over the input `RefCursor`, doing some operations to its records. No, I can't select the records inside the SP and thus avoid having to use the `RefCursor` as an input type.

I've found an example on how to do this on (this here would be the link, but it seems I cannot use them yet) Oracle's documentation, but it uses a simple `SELECT` to populate the input `RefCursor`; and therein lies the rub: I've got to populate it from code.

You see, in code I have this:

```
[OracleDataParameter("P_INPUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Input)]
private List<MiObject> cursor;
```

And, I've tried populating *cursor* with a `List<T>`, a `DataTable`, even an plain array of `MyObject`, and nothing works. When I try running my tests I get an error:

> "Invalid Parameter Linking"

Maybe not the exact wording, as I'm translating from Spanish, but that's the message

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also in contact with Mark Williams, the author of the article I've tried to link on my post, and he has kinly responded like this:

"
It is no problem to send me email; however, I think I will disappoint you with my answer on this one.

Unfortunately you can't do what you are trying to do (create a refcursor from the client like that).

A couple of problems with that are that a refcursor refers to memory owned by Oracle on the server and Oracle has no concept of client items like a DataTable or a .NET List, etc.

Do you have any other options available other than using a refcursor?
"

So basically I'm screwed, and this question is closed. Thanks for reading and/or trying to help, you all.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, isn't there an `OracleCursor` class somewhere in the ODP.NET library that works?

Comment: (Even if it exists, check that it does what you need it to... my memory is a bit hazy)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this sample](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-jan/o16odpnet.html) for refcursor as input to pl/sql from oracle technet.

The clou is that the input refcursor object must be created by oracle themself. You cannot convert a list or anything else to refcursor.

Comment: Working link to the article: http://web.archive.org/web/20080511171420/http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-jan/o16odpnet.html