# How to use Multiple Cursor Output values from procedure(package) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, plsql

```sql
Procedure GetDetails( ID as Varchar2,
                       Cursor1 OUT Cursor_Type,
                        Cursor1 OUT Cursor_Type ) AS

BEGIN

       OPEN CURSOR1 FOR 
              Select Name from User where UserID=ID;

       OPEN CURSOR2 FOR 
               Select Place from Dept where DeptID=ID;

END GetDetails;
```

How can I use Name & place values from 2 cursors?

Comment: Use refcursors [Using a ref cursor as input type with ODP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/933903/92837)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `DataReader.NextResult` to move to the next cursor.  For example:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
  //first cursor goes here
}
if (dr.NextResult() == true)
{
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    //Second cursor goes here
  }
}
```